# Twitpic OAuth switching users issue

Tags: twitter, authentication, oauth, twitpic

I'm using twitpic and logging in fine, but when changing accounts and trying to upload a pic within a short time frame (< 30 seconds) I get a "401 Unauthorized" back for a little while, and then it starts working after about a minute and my pictures upload.

This seems like maybe twitpic is caching something and it takes a little while to invalidate, or it's seeing that my IP address is the same but my oauth token is different.  Anyone else have this issue, and if so how did you solve it?

Andrew

Comment: Are you using an API with a program, or just trying this via the browser?

Comment: I'm using xAuth within an iPhone app.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. Twitpic developers couldn't help for months!

However, I figured it to ASIHTTPRequest. If you're using ASIHTTPRequest for uploading to Twitpic servers, switch back to NSURLConnection. (or figure out why ASI would have such caching issue).

Even created https://github.com/Gurpartap/GSHTTPRequest and https://github.com/Gurpartap/GSFormDataRequest quickly modeled around ASI's counterparts for the quick replacement.

Hope it works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a fix for it:

```
yourRequest.shouldAttemptPersistentConnection = NO;
```

Hope this helps!